# Accessing an instance variable from another class in Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I’m trying to access an instance variable `self.tracker` from the `gift_bot.py` file inside the `cogs/invite_moduly.py` file. However, I’m not sure how to do this. I’ve tried several methods like `self.bot.tracker`, `tracker`, and more, but none of them worked. How can I access this variable in `invite_module.py`?

#### File *gift_bot.py*

```
class GiftBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracker = InviteTracker(self)
        super().__init__(command_prefix="*", intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)

    async def on_ready(self):

        try:
            await self.tracker.cache_invites()
        except:
            pass
```

#### cogs/invite_module.py:

```
class InviteModule(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot


        self.last_member: list = []

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_member_join")
    async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member):
        invite_info = await get_inviter(self.tracker, member)
```

How can I access the `self.tracker` variable from the `gift_bot.py` file inside the `cogs/invite_moduly.py` file? Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `self` is just a name. It's bound to an instance of `GiftBot` inside `GitBot` methods; you need some other way to get an instance of `GiftBot` inside `InviteModule.on_member_join`. (Or some other way to get an instance of `InviteTracker` to pass to `get_inviter`.)

Comment: Yeah i know but i don't know how can I get the instance.

Comment: What instance? Where does `GiftBot` get instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you instantiate `InviteModule` with `bot` being a reference to an instance of `GiftBot`, it would be `self.bot.tracker`.

`self` is used to reference the instance of the class where's that method (by convention, it's **not** a keyword, but it's discouraged to use something other than `self`). So, inside `InviteModule`, `self` is an object of the class `InviteModule`, and inside `GiftBot`, it's an object the class `GiftBot`.

If you want to reference a property of `GiftBot` inside `InviteModule`, you must pass an instance of `GiftBot` to `InviteModule`¹, which I assume you're doing as the `bot` property. So, to access it **inside** `InviteModule` use `self.bot`, and hence, the tracker would be `self.bot.tracker`.

---

¹ Or, instead of passing the whole bot, you could pass the property itself. For instance, you could do:

```py
class InviteModule(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, tracker):
        self.tracker = tracker

        # rest of the code here
```

And use as:

```py
giftBot = GiftBot()
inviteModule = InviteModule(giftBot.tracker)
```

I assume you want the first option, but I'm adding this for completeness.

---

*I can be wrong, but I believe the error mentioned in the comments is actually from the IDE.*

Per your comment, I suppose class `Bot` does not have the field tracker. So, you could either:

1. Change `InviteModule` init to accept `GiftBot`
2. Before trying to access the field `tracker`, check if the element is an instance of GiftBot.

If there's nothing usable in `InviteModule` without the field `tracker`, the first option is probably better:

```py
class InviteModule(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: GiftBot): # or gift_bot.GiftBot, depending on how you're importing/connecting those files
        self.bot = bot

        # rest of the code
```

The second option would go something like:

```py
class InviteModule(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        # rest of init

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_member_join")
    async def on_member_join(self, member: discord.Member):
        if instanceof(self.bot, GiftBot):
            invite_info = await get_inviter(self.bot.tracker, member)
        # if not instance, define what's desired: ignore, log only, throw an error
```

Comment: I tried the first option already, but i got `Unresolved attribute reference 'tracker' for class 'Bot'`

Comment: Oh, I get it. InviteModule expects a Bot, which does NOT have the field tracker; only the child class GiftBot has it. Either you change InviteModule to accept an GiftBot, or you check/cast Bot inside to GiftBot.